# Ruby on Rails, Grocer cannot send to push notification multiple recipients

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-push-notifications

```
  def push_notification(users)

    unless self.pushed_to_mobile? || users.empty?

      # make sure all required users receive notifications on
      # all registered devices.
      @device_tokens = users.map { |u| u.device_tokens }.flatten.uniq

      @device_tokens.each do |token|

        notification = Grocer::Notification.new(
          device_token:   token.device_token,
           alert:        { "body" => "#{self.context_type}: #{self.name}", "action-loc-key" => "View" },
           badge:        1,
           sound:        'chord.aiff'
           custom:       { "content" => [ self.name, self.context_type, self.context_name, self.context_id, self.content_id ] },
        )

        feedback.each do |attempt|
        #   # TODO: if a device fails 3 times it should be removed from the token list.
        #   # Failing 3 times indicates that the user has turned notifications off or
        #   # removed the app from the phone. If the user logs in and their token does
        #   # not exist it will be readded.
          puts "Device #{attempt.device_token} failed at #{attempt.timestamp}"
        end

        pusher.push( notification )

      end
    end

    # update model to prevent notifying again.
    self.pushed_to_mobile = true
    self.save
  end

  def pusher
    return @pusher if defined?( @pusher )
    @pusher = Grocer.pusher(
      certificate: Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:certificate],
      passphrase:  Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:pass],
      gateway:     Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:host],
      retries:     3
    )
  end

  def feedback
    return @feedback if defined?( @feedback )
    @feedback = Grocer.feedback(
      certificate: Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:certificate],
      passphrase:  Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:pass],
      gateway:     Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:host],
      retries:     3
    )
  end
```

If I remove the loop and force the code to send to a single token, the code runs and the push notification is received on the device. However if I attempt to loop through an array of users.device_tokens the code executes without error, but the notification is never received on device.

edit: Even if the loop only runs once it works.

Comment: I'm working on a theory here, could you pleae try removing the `feedback.each` iterator from within the `@device_tokens.each` iterator?

Comment: Approximately how long does it take to execute the `@device_tokens.each ...` block when you loop through the entire structure?

Comment: @jmera Haven't timed it, however if I sleep(0.01) the notifications are received on the devices.

Comment: @BartJedrocha I'll try this, however the feedback is a necessity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related with the way you're accessing the `Grocer::Feedback` socket. Try changing your `feedback` method to the following.

```
def feedback
  @feedback ||= Grocer.feedback(
    certificate: Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:certificate],
    passphrase:  Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:pass],
    gateway:     Settings.apple_push_notification_options[:host],
    retries:     3
  )
  @feedback.to_a
end
```

Calling the `to_a` will force a reading of whatever is currently on the feedback socket.